# After assigning multiple pointers to the same object and checking the addresses, only one of the pointers points to the right one

Tags: c++, pointers

I'm making a game for a C++ class and am having trouble with the pointers.  In order to equip items to the character I created 8 pointers for the different wearable item types. I also made a class called noItem which inherits from all of the item types and initializes all attributes to zero.  When I create my character, I make an instance of noItem and make all the pointers point to that instance however when I check the addresses the pointers are pointing to, only one of them points to the address of the instance of noItem.

I tried rearranging the order of the pointer assignments and it's always the same pointer that has the right one regardless of when I make it point to the instance of noItem and the rest point to an address close to the address of the instance of noItem but never actually there.  I even tried making an instance of noItem for every item type but the same problem occured.

```
class parent1 {

};

class parent2 {

};

class child : public parent1, public parent2 {

};


int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv [])
{
parent1 *p1;
parent2 *p2;

child a;

p1 = &a;
p2 = &a;

cout << &a << endl;
cout << p1 << endl;
cout << p2 << endl;

system("pause");

}
```

In this example p1 points to &a but p2 points to another address.  If I change the order in which the child inherits from the parent classes, p2 will point to &a but p1 will point to another address.  Why does this happen?

Comment: Could you please post the code?

Comment: There's sufficient information in the question, you just have to read the English.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you state, your `noItem` class is derived from many other types, e.g. `Helmet`. That means that somewhere in the `noItem` object, there's a `Helmet` sub-object. It may be at the beginning, but there can be only one sub-object located there (usually the first base class, ignoring complicated inheritance schemes).

Look through your pointers. There's one which you claim is "correct". That's pointing to the first base class subobject. Now calculate `sizeof(*correctPointer)`. That will tell you where the second subobject can begin. There could be some padding, but in general this will be exactly the mysterious difference.

Answer (score 1):

You say you did this

```
class Helm {}
class Legs {}
class Sleeves {}
class noItem : public Helm, public Legs, public Sleeves {}
```

instead you should do something like

```
class Item {}
class Helm : public Item {}
class Legs : public Item {}
class Sleeves : public Item {}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a vector or list of pointers to your item base class. Allocate and insert your items to the list as required. Don't hardcode a set number of items. Lacking an item is best represented by not having anything.